# Extend StagedModelDataHandler for Journal Article in Staging

Tags: liferay, liferay-7, staging, liferay-7.1

I am working on local live staging in Liferay 7.1, in which I have one custom field in Web content. When I export those web content to local live, I want to check that custom field as result I would be export that web content.

So for that, I am extending doExportStagedModel in BaseStagedModelDataHandler as below.

```
@Component(immediate = true,service = {StagedModelDataHandler.class})
public class Demo extends BaseStagedModelDataHandler<JournalArticle> {

     // All the stuff


    @Override
    protected void doExportStagedModel(
            PortletDataContext portletDataContext, JournalArticle article)
        throws Exception {


          // overridden stuff
     }



     // Other stuff
}
```

When I am deploying this, I got below exception.

> 2018-11-20 04:04:12.669 ERROR The setJournalCreationStrategy method
>   has thrown an exception  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument
>   type mismatch
>
> 2018-11-20 04:04:12.850 ERROR The
>   setJournalFeedExportImportContentProcessor method has thrown an
>   exception  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch

Does anybody having idea how can I do this proper way on this?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please [link your crossposts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141823/is-cross-posting-wrong-to-an-external-site), or better: Don't crosspost

Comment: @OlafKock : I am really seeking help from Liferay community. Please help me on this. If you need more information let me know I will provide you.